# Get process and thread affinity mask on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, affinity

On Windows, there exists the GetProcessAffinityMask API call, and there also exists a roundabout way of finding the thread affinity mask, seen here:

[Query thread (not process) processor affinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601862/query-thread-not-process-processor-affinity)

Is there any way of getting this information in Linux? A call to sched_getcpu() returns only the cpu that the thread is *currently* running on, not its affinity mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sched_setaffinity() & sched_getaffinity()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html).

[pthread_attr_setaffinty_np() & pthread_attr_getaffinity_np()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_setaffinity_np.3.html).

[pthread_setaffinity_np() & pthread_getaffinity_np()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

The _np stands for non-portable.